# How to get value in JSON - Google API

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, google-api, nsdictionary

i'm currently developping an app which recover data in json, and put theses in a tableview, directly connected to a view.
I succeed to retrieve data and put them in my cell, but i have problem with some data which not come properly.

I get my data from the search api of google, this my request :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=chicha+lyon&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDfdpFcPFSr-0lTaxsyia84VU0VAsgEt1c"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//AFNetworking asynchronous url request
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking = [responseObject objectForKey:@"results"];
```

I created a new dictionnary to store datas as like that :

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and my json is :

```
"results" : [ 

  {
     "formatted_address" : "3 Rue Jangot, 69007 Lyon, France",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 45.752138,
           "lng" : 4.842072
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png",
     "id" : "0c5eca79397af5123a9c9642ff73eec2f55680aa",
     "name" : "Le CRISTAL Lounge",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "**open_now" : false,**
        "weekday_text" : []
     },
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 1481,
           "html_attributions" : [],
           "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAArPewwyAnXVPJcMTaMhJjIYzQMRoFz-WTiFVGkjIGXEfmKxMdWCgFzv9uNa3HPDRqWq0pojuUFbKBt4l0a6zoACU27t0F1noEQoysGnWb7JVTM5lR0uoCCTtumpibtSZpXsECrAHN140s4vAogQAh-RIQ0kuRl7kKzNmTQy6as30x2BoUrNMkQKrMVS2Mnu9pi5tgw7N1UcQ",
           "width" : 2048
        }
```

I want to get the value of "open_now",  but i do not succeed :(.
I tried many thing, but the best i got, is :

2015-04-06 12:28:56.099 WebTableView[14851:1734075] The Array: 0

2015-04-06 12:28:56.100 WebTableView[14851:1734075] The Array: 1

2015-04-06 12:28:56.101 WebTableView[14851:1734075] The Array: 1

2015-04-06 12:28:56.102 WebTableView[14851:1734075] The Array: (null)

2015-04-06 12:28:56.103 WebTableView[14851:1734075] The Array: (null)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: post the code where you try to access the "open_now" property...

Comment: I tried :                                                                                                   NSArray *openhours = [tempdictionnary objectForKey:@"opening_hours"];
NSDictionary *firstvalue = [openhours objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fieldOne = [firstvalue objectForKey:@"open_now"];                                                                         but currently i have :                                                                              NSArray *items = [tempDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"opening_hours.open_now"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, the value for key `opening_hours` is a dictionary :

```
NSMutableDictionary *openhours = [tempdictionnary objectForKey:@"opening_hours"];

BOOL firstvalue = [openhours objectForKey:@"open_now"];
```

Comment: firstly , thank's for helping me , i tried, and xcode tell me : Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *') is disallowed with ARC

Comment: comment out the second line and add this line instead : `NSLog([[openhours objectForKey:@"open_now"] class]);`. The use the class which is shown in the log to store the value.

Comment: i got "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" with NSLog([[openhours objectForKey:@"open_now"] class]);

Comment: i changed for : NSLog(@"The Array: %@",openhours); , and i have now : 2015-04-06 14:17:40.911 WebTableView[16043:2059054] The Array: {
    "open_now" = 0;
    "weekday_text" =     (
    );
}
2015-04-06 14:17:40.912 WebTableView[16043:2059054] The Array: (null)

Comment: is the `NSLog` actually supposed to print twice?

Comment: no :/ ,  normally the nslog should return only the value of "open_now", cause i want to create a condition which say, if "open_now" = 1 so print "open" else print "close". but currently i got two result "1", and "Null" so it doesn't work..

Comment: i think its a problem with your outside loop. it seems to be running more than the count of the array.

Comment: Great it works now, i just realised some value are missing in the json, so when my log return "Null" it's normal. i succeed to create my condition, it work like a charm in my condition but if i ask a log with "open_now", it return "null". Anyway, thank's a lot for your help !